# Write to a file at compile time in C++?

Tags: c++, file, compile-time

I was doing some C++ metaprogramming, and I had the following code:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    // not allowed
    constexpr {
        ofstream foo("foo.asm");
        foo << "incq   %rax\n";
        foo.close();
    }

    __asm(
        #include "foo.asm"
    );
}
```

#### foo.asm

```
        movw   $255, %ax
        movw   $1137, %bx
        addb   %bl, %al\n
        adcb   %bh, %ah
```

Is it possible to write to this file at compile-time?

Comment: C or C++?  You say C in the Q, but you have a cpp file, which is usually meant for C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was originally doing it in C, but I don't mind an answer that only works in C++, but good point, I changed it

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick Thanks.  For this, you're going to want to utilize a build system.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Why would you want to generate inline assembly block instead of using preprocessor or templates (typical ways to do some metaprogramming in C++)?

Comment: @user7860670 I wanted to compile another file, take the output, and insert it into `main` at compile-time

Comment: You may want to check https://github.com/mattbierner/Super-Template-Tetris

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick: Keep in mind that when you compile another function, you get the assembly including function prolog and epilog. But your `main` has its own prologs and epilogs. Additionally, these can be special because `main` is a special function.

Comment: @MSalters it's not too difficult to filter out the prolog and epilogue

Comment: I looked a bit further. repl.it started with scripting languages, where the editor and the runtime environment are mixed. In C++ the two are quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

However, most build systems will allow you to execute any code you want right before they compile the file, it's not really meta-programming but it might solve your issue.

Comment: How would I do so?

Comment: Visual Studio example - right click projects -> properties -> Build Events -> Pre Build Event -> Command Line.

Comment: do you mean before I compile it?

Comment: A pre-build event in Visual Studio fires before you build (F7). You can also compile a single file (Ctrl-F7) but that does not trigger Pre-Build events.

Comment: I don't have visual studio, I'm using https://repl.it, but thanks anyway

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick: That's a rather complex build environment behind the scenes. Of course, the idea of repl.it is to make simple things simple. But the price often is to make hard things impossible.  And what you want is _really_ hard.